# Phar::decompress - Does the example on php.net have an error?

Tags: php

http://php.net/manual/en/phar.decompress.php

```
<?php
$p = new Phar('/path/to/my.phar', 0, 'my.phar.gz');
$p['myfile.txt'] = 'hi';
$p['myfile2.txt'] = 'hi';
$p3 = $p2->decompress(); // creates /path/to/my.phar
?>
```

$p2 is used for the first time on the 5th line of the code. It was not set before and I am not sure where it would be coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are completly correct.

As the variable was not declared before, and there is no require statement or any thing else which could create or import that variable, this is most probably an error in the php doc.
I guess it should be `$p` and not `$p2`.